# Is there a way to patch object across processes?

Tags: python

I have a main python process which runs another python process. I want to patch or set some attribute of the child process so that it uses only what I set for it rather than what's defined in it.

To elucidate: child process has a function foo() but i want to change it to foobar() in my parent so that when foo gets 'called' it executes 'foobar' instead.

I'm pretty sure this is called monkey-patching from what i have learnt but i dont know what others refer to it as

This is mainly for testing the code I developed

I tried using preexec_fn in Popen() to change the function entirely

In my child process:

```
def foo():
   "do this"
```

In my parent:

```
def foobar():
    print "do this instead"

def pre_exec():
    import child
    setattr(child, 'foo', foobar)

Popen(['python', 'child.py'],preexec_fn=pre_exec)
```

I expected it to print "do this instead" but the actual output was "do this".

Any help or idea is appreciated!

Comment: Are you testing? If so, did you look at the Mock or MagicMock classes from unittest?

Comment: Yes I have tried MagicMock, didn't help. Also I'm limited to just this method because the platform I'm using doesn't support or have MagicMock  edit: typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note, but monkey patching makes debugging awful. While it was a common practice in Ruby, it's always been frowned upon in python. If you absolutely have to do it, you need to mark out whatever you're doing in a huge comment explaining why you couldn't do without it to whoever inherits your code.

So, if you want a child process to do something different than the main one, the most appropriate thing to do is to pass it an argument.

When you call the child, it should passed an argument to let it know to swap out the function.

```
Popen(['python', 'child.py', '--use-alternate-function'])
```

edit: the pre exec function is a function called after your program forks ( makes a copy of itself in memory ) and before the child copy calls exec ( which swaps it out for a new fresh copy of the program name you gave it ). It's for setting environment variables or whatever in a single threaded environment. I've never needed to touch it in years of using python.

Comment: Thanks for the insight but this method isn't accepted because what I'm trying to achieve is only for testing. The actual implementation doesn't require a secondary functionality. Also what I have shown is only an example. I might, for all unknown reasons need to patch an class in the child using a class in the parent before instantiating.

Comment: After putting some thought into this, i feel this is the best approach but its only partially. What would be easier is to call another file instead, lets say 'before_child.py' which then patches the child allowing you to gain control over it. So now your 'before_child.py' has all the patches you intended and could have done if your child wasn't a subprocess call